Rational quaternions are division sub algebra of any cyclic division algebra over a number field
If $L$ is a finite cyclic Galois extension of degree $n$ over a number field $K$, $\theta\in\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)$ is a generator, and $a\in K$ nonzero is such that $a^n$ is the least power of $a$ that is the field norm of some element in $L$, we can form the following cyclic division algebra:
$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{K}:=L\oplus L\mathbf{j}\oplus\dots\oplus L\mathbf{j}^{n-1}
\end{align*}$
where $\mathbf{j}$ satisfies
$\begin{align*}
(\forall \alpha\in L)\ \mathbf{j}\alpha=\theta(\alpha)\mathbf{j}\ \wedge\ \mathbf{j}^n=a.
\end{align*}$
In an article I'm reading, they state that from the case $L=\mathbb{C}$, $K=\mathbb{R}$ (which aren't number fields), $\theta=$complex conjugation, and $a=-1$, which results in $\mathbb{H}$, Hamilton's quaternions, it's "easy to see" that the rational quaternions $\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{i}\oplus\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{j}\oplus\mathbb{Q}\mathrm{k}$ form the smallest cyclic division sub algebra of an arbitrary cyclic division algebra over a number field. This is not obvious to me at all and I have been trying to see it hold up in a particular case. Namely, when $L=\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$, $K=\mathbb{Q}$ with $\xi=2\cos\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)$ being a root of $X^3+X^2-2X-1$ and the relations
$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{j}\xi=(\xi^2-2)\mathbf{j}\ \wedge\ \mathbf{j}^3=2.
\end{align*}$
I thought that my first step in finding the rational quaternions within this division algebra would be to find an element such that it squares to $-1$. I tried to do this with matrix representations of the cyclic division algebra which gives me a $3\times 3$ matrices but the entries are all real since $L$ is a totally real number field and there do not exist $3\times 3$ matrices which square to the negative identity matrix. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is false. (Are you sure this is what was claimed?) If $D$ is a division algebra of odd dimension over its center $K$ then it can't contain any even-dimensional division algebras $D'$ over $K$, since otherwise $D$ would be a $D'$-vector space and hence we would have $\dim D' \mid \dim D$.

Thanks for the clarification. The statement appears on arXiv:1912.02555, a little below Remark 4.4. It does state "the number field $K$" so now I'm wondering if the author is building these off a particular one but at first read it didn't seem like it.

@Ama: I am sorry to have to say it, but that remark about the rational quaternions is nonsense and much of the rest of the paper also appears to be nonsense to me. I think there is no way Theorems 2.6 or 4.1 could possibly be true in an interesting way (they can be true in a boring way, e.g. as written one could write down such functors which send every homeomorphism to an identity morphism).

For a more specific issue with this paper, I do not believe that Lemma 2.5 is correct. He claims that $C(a)$ is Dedekind-Hecke, meaning its outer automorphism group contains $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup. But since $C(a)$ is central simple over $K$, its outer automorphism group over $K$ is trivial by Skolem-Noether. And its outer automorphism group over $\mathbb{Z}$ is (at best) the automorphism group of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is finite.

His proof certainly does not work; he says to take $g$ to be conjugation by an upper triangular matrix but does not verify that this conjugation preserves $C(a)$. Also, it is true that every automorphism of $C(a)$ is given by conjugation by an element of $M_n(K)$ but this does not follow just from the (central) simplicity of $M_n(K)$; we also need the simplicity of $C(a)$ to apply Skolem-Noether. In addition to this there are several strange typos, e.g. he writes $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ at several points when he means $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know what to make of this.

The author of that paper is has a long history of papers which are more or less crank articles. Plenty of his articles "prove" patently false results.

@user297024: thanks for this, that's what it looked like but I couldn't find anyone else saying so. Apparently he gave a talk at JMM 2018...?

In https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2021.1915324 he references S.A. Amitsur's paper "A non commutative Hilbert basis theorem and subrings of matrices". Specifically, in the proof of Lemma 3.1, based on his paraphrasing I'm led to believe that from Amitsur's paper you can conclude "if you have a finite dimensional extension $\mathbb{K}$ of a cyclic division algebra $\mathbb{L}$ and $O_{\mathbb{L}}$ is an arbitrary maximal order of $\mathbb{L}$ that is noetherian, then an arbitrary maximal order of $\mathbb{K}$, $O_{\mathbb{K}}$, is also noetherian. Is this accurate?

@Ama: on the one hand there is probably no point in trying to read these papers, and on the other hand I don't know anything about orders in noncommutative algebras. But any torsion-free ring of finite rank should be noetherian, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian.

I can deduce that the additive group of the ring in question is torsion-free of finite rank, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$ for some $r>0$, but, since multiplication is not commutative, how can I deduce that the ring is noetherian, i.e., that all two-sided ideals are finitely generated?

@Ama: the ascending chain condition holds for submodules of $\mathbb{Z}^r$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian. So in particular it holds for left, right, or two-sided ideals wrt any ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}^r$, commutative or otherwise. But the bigger question is: why are you trying to read these papers when they are full of nonsense?

@QiaochuYuan I picked this paper to write a report on for class but when I initially picked it I wasn't familiar enough with structures like cyclic division algebras to understand the proofs. I picked it because I like to study connections between knot theory and algebra. Now it's too late to switch.

@Ama: my condolences. Well, there is interesting material in the vicinity of this stuff you can read (hopefully more correct) papers about. For example quaternion algebras appear in the context of what are called arithmetic hyperbolic $3$-manifolds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_hyperbolic_3-manifold
